# Delphi XE3 com mensagem de erro IWBaseHTMLControl intraweb vrs: 14.0.34

Tags: delphi-xe3

Uso o Delphi XE3 e atualizei a minha versão do IntraWeb para vrs:14.0.34.

A instalação correu bem, porém ao usar o componente `IWCompFileUploader` está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit2.pas(8): F2051 Unit IWCompFileUploader was compiled with a different version of IWBaseHTMLControl.TIWBaseHTMLControl.get_NonEditableAsLabel

Será que alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Você tem mais de uma versão do delphi instalado?

Comment: obrigado Pessoal, descobri a causa deste erro, tenho o Delphi XE3 com IntraWeb 14.0.17 embarcada,  tinha desinstalado e instalado a versão 14.0.34 por fora e não deu certo ocasionando o erro acima, então voltei pra versão embarcada mesmo;